# Play 2 and AWS DynamoDB - is there a reactive api library available?

Tags: playframework-2.0, amazon-dynamodb

ReactiveMongo exists to allow us to be 'reactive' with Mongo. Does such a library exist for connecting to AWS DynamoDB in a reactive, non-blocking fashion. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodb/AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient.html) from the [AWS Java SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/) as a non-blocking client.

Comment: To my understanding the AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient only returns a Java Future which is not the same as a Scala Future and also blocking (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366277/what-are-the-differences-between-a-scala-future-and-a-java-future).

Answer (score 2):

As per AWS docs, there is no fully non-blocking, reactive SDK for Dynamo.
The mentioned "AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient" doesn't block the caller thread(The thread which has triggered as dynamodb request) but there is still a thread internally being used and blocked. It is just a helper utility for developers but it would not save from thread hell.

Ref: [AWS blog](https://java.awsblog.com/post/TxLD9V4E1WQLCP/Asynchronous-Requests-with-the-AWS-SDK-for-Java)

But do check "https://github.com/piotrga/async-dynamo" which is built on 
Akka framework which has asyncIO support from groundup. But I didnt personally try this