# What are the differences between a Scala Future and a Java Future

Tags: java, scala

Are there any conceptual, functional or mechanical differences between a Scala Future and a Java Future? Conceptually I can't see any differences as they both aim to provide a mechanism for asynchronous computation.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The main inconvenience of `java.util.concurrent.Future` is the fact that you can't get the value without blocking.

In fact, the only way to retrieve a value is the `get` method, that ([quoting from the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html))

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

With `scala.concurrent.Future` you get instead a real non-blocking computation, as you can attach callbacks for completion (success/failure) or simply map over it and chain multiple Futures together in a monadic fashion.

Long story short, scala's Future allows for asynchronous computation without blocking more threads than necessary.

Comment: Maybe it would be more precise to say that scala has a more convenient api to interact with pending Futures and callback. I am not sure thaough how that comparison is with Java8 CompletableFuture, though that one is not returned by standard executors.

Comment: There are various methods in `CompletableFuture` that allow non-blocking computation just as in Scala, although the API is less readable.

Comment: Yep, CompletableFuture is nicer, I'm strictly talking about java.concurrent.Future in my answer

Answer (score 4):

**Java Future**:Both represent result of an Asynchronous computation,but Java's **Future** requires that you access the result via a blocking get method.Although you can call **isDone** to find out if a **Java Future** has completed before calling get, thereby avoiding any blocking, you must wait until the Java Future has completed before proceeding with any computation that uses the result.

**Scala Future**: You can specify transformations on a **Scala Future** whether it has completed or not.Each transformation results in a new **Future** representing the asynchronous result of the original **Future** transformed by the function. This allows you to describe asynchronous computations as a series of transformations.

**Scala's Future** often eliminate, the need to reason about shared data and locks.When you invoke a Scala method, it performs a computation "while you wait" and returns a result. If that result is a Future, the Future represents another computation to be performed asynchronously often by a completely different thread.

**Example**: Instead of blocking then continuing with another computation, you can just map the next computation onto the future.

Following future will complete after ten seconds:

```
val fut = Future { Thread.sleep(10000);21+21}
```

Mapping this future with a function that increments by one will yield another future.

```
 val result = fut.map(x=>x+1)
```